# How to darken image using x-window lib in linux

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, xlib, imaging

I am going to darken image using x lib in Ubuntu. Here is my code.

```
XImage* getCorrectedImage(Pixmap p){
   int buflen, i;
   XImage* img = XGetImage(g_display, p, 0, 0, g_width, g_height,    AllPlanes, ZPixmap);
   buflen = img->width * img->height * img->bitmap_pad / 8;
   for(i = 0; i < buflen; i++){
      img->data[i] /= 2;
   }
}
```

And the result image is like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm wondering if you are altering a gamma value in addition to the RGB values you are expecting to alter. img->data contains more than the RGB triple, more than likely it contains 4 bytes, possibly also the alpha value. Try using XGetPixel()/XSetPixel() to change the values.

Comment: That's an interesting choice of image for an Ubuntu machine. My unscientific guess is that you are trying to manipulate an idexed-colour 8-bit Pixmap. BTW bitmap_pad is NOT the number of bytes per pixel.

Answer (score 0):

It is problem in color mode. it is not 24bit color mode
you have to use 16bit color mode

Comment: That's interesting. do you mean 24 bit mode?